# Чи є українські відповідники до слова "корпоратив"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

Доволі часто використовуємо слово **"корпоратив"**, **"корпоративна вечірка"**. Однак я зацікавилась саме його відповідником - питомим словом, яке б передавало його значення. Якщо ввести у google, то одразу вибиває значення терміну, його види та ін. Відповідника, чомусь, не знайшла. Для прикладу подаю статтю ["Що таке корпоратив і яким він може бути?"](http://faqukr.ru/biznes/101245-shho-take-korporativ-i-jakim-vin-mozhe-buti.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/korporatyv) знаходимо такі відповідники:

> колегулька, робоча вечірка, робопляс, гуртівка, фірмова забава, внутрішня вечірка, гультяйня, гуртяйнівка, фірмові гульки.

На [druzy.com.ua](http://druzy.com.ua/sho-take-korporativ-znachennia-i-pravopis-slova/) знаходимо такі синоніми до слова корпоратив:

> • вечірка;
>   •   свято;
>   •   гулянка;
>   •   пиятика;
>   •   банкет;
>   •   фуршет.